# siunitx: Always force two decimal numbers behind decimal marker

Tags: siunitx, decimal-number, number

I want to display `2.00 m` instead of `2 m`, even if the leading number is not a decimal number (= is an integer).

Unfortunately all `\sisetup`-commands I tried did not work...

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \SI{2}{\meter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to round and convert integers to decimals

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 2, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

    \SI{2}{\metre}

\end{document}
```

(Probably in v3, in development, you won't need `round-integer-to-decimal`: I suspect this was one of my less-good ideas!)

Comment: Man, I was looking for that since one hour... :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dave - For more in-depth information on the topic of your query, do check out Section 5.5 of the user guide of the `siunitx` package, beginning on p. 22.