# Creating a bold header for a table with the csvsimple, siunitx, and tokcycle packages

Tags: tables, siunitx, bold, csvsimple

I found [this post](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3293), illustrating how to typeset the header of a table in bold face. Combining it with `\csvreader` from the `csvsimple` package worked fine, as long as I don't format the numbers using `siunitx` package. Below `\sisetup` fixes two decimal points as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436761/siunitx-always-force-two-decimal-numbers-behind-decimal-marker/436762).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple, siunitx, booktabs, array}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
Player, Merlin, Mordred
Andrew, 0.6, 0.55
Ben, 0.54, 0.62
\end{filecontents*}

\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{-}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}#1\ignorespaces}

\csvstyle{boldhead}{
    no head,
    table head=\toprule\rowstyle{\bfseries},
    late after first line=\\ \midrule, 
    table foot=\bottomrule
}
\sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=2, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[tabular=+l-c-c, boldhead]{sample.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}

\end{document}
```

I think there are three problems with this solution:

1. The option `head to column names` cannot be used because the `no head` option is loaded. Is there a better way to display the header using `\csvreader` that preserves the possibility of using  `head to column names`?
2. If I replace `tabular=+l-c-c` with `tabular=+l-S-S`, then the table no longer typesets because the `siunitx` package does not recognize the header and throws the error `invalid numerical input 'e'`.
3. Personally, I'd prefer typing `lcc` instead of `+l-c-c`.

Since the number formatting of the `siunitx` package can be escaped with a group, my idea for point 2 was to include a `\bgroup` `\egroup` pair into the rowstyle as follows:

```
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax\global\let\currentrowstylepost\relax}}
\newcolumntype{-}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcolumntype{^}{<{\currentrowstylepost}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{%
    \gdef\currentrowstylepost{\egroup}%
    \gdef\currentrowstyle{#1\bgroup}%
    #1\bgroup\ignorespaces%
}
```

While the above code works for option `tabular=+l^-c^-c^`, it still does not work for `tabular=+l^-S^-S^`. What am I missing?

Regarding point 3, one would imagine that this can be fixed with the `tokcycle` package. This was my attempt.

```
\settcEscapechar{:}
\newif\iffirstchar
\Characterdirective{%
    \ifx#1|%
        #1%
    \else%
        \iffirstchar%
            \global\firstcharfalse%
            +#1%
        \else%
            -#1%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\csvboldreader}[4]{%
    \global\firstchartrue%
    \csvreader[tabular=\tokencyclexpress #1\endtokencyclexpress, boldhead]{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\begin{document}
\csvboldreader{lcc}{sample.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it throws an error `illegal token 'c' used`. If I call

```
\tokencyclexpress lcc\endtokencyclexpress
```

in isolation, the string is transformed correctly. What am I missing?

I have to admit I am not too familiar with the `siunitx` package and figured I'd tag on two more questions about it:

4. What is the cleanest `\sisetup` to align numbers centered with the header, but among each other aligned according to the decimal point? Is there a better way than setting `{S[table-format=1.2]}` etc. manually for each column?
5. What is the `@{}` used for that appears in the `siunitx` manual? My first guess was that one doesn't have to use braces for each column, but that appears to be incorrect since `tabular=@{} l S S[table-format=2.2] @{}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See SUPPLEMENT for alternative.

As to the `tokcycle` portion of the question (item No. 3), there were two problems with the approach posted:

1. Running the token cycle inside of `\csvreader` optional argument does not work.
2. Even passing a macro with the proper tokens, as in `tabular=\mypreamble`, does not work.  It must be passed the *actual tokens* of the `tabular` preamble.

Thus, several things were needed.  The token cycle had to be performed in advance of the `\csvreader` invocation and the result had to be saved in the `\cytoks` token list.  This required the `\Characterdirective` to be changed from the direct output of `<tokens>` to the equivalent `\addcytoks{<tokens>}` format.  By using `\tokcyclexpress` (macro) rather than `\tokencyclexpress` (pseudo-environment), the automatic typsetting of `\the\cytoks` output is suppressed, even as the result is stored in `\cytoks`.

So far, so good.  But even here, `tabular=\the\cytoks` as an option in `\csvreader` does not work.  So, the invocation had to be broken into two parts: `\def\tmp{\csvreader[tabular=}`  followed by `\expandafter\tmp\the\cytoks, boldhead]{#2}{#3}{#4}`.  In this way, `\the\cytoks` expanded into the actual desired tokens prior to the invocation of `\csvreader`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple, siunitx, booktabs, array,tokcycle}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sample.csv}
Player, Merlin, Mordred
Andrew, 0.6, 0.55
Ben, 0.54, 0.62
\end{filecontents*}

\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{-}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}#1\ignorespaces}

\csvstyle{boldhead}{
    no head,
    table head=\toprule\rowstyle{\bfseries},
    late after first line=\\ \midrule, 
    table foot=\bottomrule
}
\sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=2, round-integer-to-decimal}

\settcEscapechar{:}
\newif\iffirstchar
\Characterdirective{%
    \ifx#1|%
        \addcytoks{#1}%
    \else%
        \iffirstchar%
            \global\firstcharfalse%
            \addcytoks{+#1}%
        \else%
            \addcytoks{-#1}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\csvboldreader}[4]{%
    \global\firstchartrue%
    \tokcyclexpress{#1}%
    \def\tmp{\csvreader[tabular=}%
    \expandafter\tmp\the\cytoks, boldhead]{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\begin{document}
\csvboldreader{lcc}{sample.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

Here is an alternative approach that supports the `siunitx` column types as well as a bolded (or other) first line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx, booktabs, array, tokcycle, readarray}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sample.csv}
Player, Merlin, Mordred
Andrew, 0.6, 0.55
Ben, 0.54, 0.62
\end{filecontents*}
\sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=2, round-integer-to-decimal}
\newif\iffirstrow
\Characterdirective{%
  \iffirstrow
    \tctestifx{,#1}{\addcytoks{&\xxcmd}}{\addcytoks{{#1}}}
  \else
    \tctestifx{,#1}{\addcytoks{&}}{\addcytoks{#1}}
  \fi
}
\Macrodirective{%
  \iffirstrow
    \tctestifx{\\#1}{\firstrowfalse\addcytoks{#1\midrule}}{\addcytoks{#1}}
  \else
    \addcytoks{#1}
  \fi
}
\newcommand\csvxreader[3][\bfseries]{%
  \readarraysepchar{\\}%
  \readdef{#3}\mytab
  \firstrowtrue
  \def\xxcmd{#1}%
  \expandafter\tokcyclexpress\expandafter{\mytab}%
  \begin{tabular}{#2}%
  \toprule
  #1%
  \the\cytoks
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\csvxreader[\scshape]{lcc}{sample.csv}

\bigskip
\csvxreader{lSS}{sample.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Let me see if I understand correctly. The `\tokcyclexpress` cannot be called within an argument because it is a fragile command (as, presumably, most other commands in the package?). Second, `\the\cytoks` needs to be expanded before it is processed by `\csvreader`. Because `\expandafter` looks ahead only one token, we need to store the rest in `\tmp`. Correct?

I need some time to process the alternative answer as I was not aware of the `readarray` package until today. Thanks for pointing me towards it!

Comment: @S.Olafsson Not because `\tokcyclexpress` is *fragile*, but because it is *unexpandable* (because its execution involves *assignments*, as in `\def`, `\let`, and `\futurelet`).  The rest of your comment is on point.  The `\tmp` storage was particularly helpful here, otherwise, to expandafter an input like `[tabular=` would require `\expandafter [\expandafter t\expandafter a\expandafter b\expandafter u\expandafter l\expandafter a\expandafter r\expandafter =`.  You can see the problem here.

Comment: @S.Olafsson The `readarray` package is due for an upgrade.  See my **SUPPLEMENT** at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498008/set-value-in-readarray/498009#498009 to see the sort of upgrade it will be.